# JS numbers in MAC OS and Windows

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have this issue where writing js code

```
var sub_total = 10000;
var total = sub_total.toLocaleString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");


console.log(total);
```

Result in Mac OS is 10,000 (with a comma as thousand separator)
Result in Windows is 10.000 (with a dot as thousand separator)

Comment: `toLocaleString` renders your number according to the user's current locale. If you, for example, use "en", it'll use a `,` as a separator. If you use "de", it'll use a `.`. You can add an argument to explicitly always render it in one locale: `toLocaleString("en")` or `toLocaleString("de")`. That might or might not be a good idea depending on your use case.

Comment: This is more likely due to your Mac OS machine having been set up with a different locale than your Windows machine. Check that and [edit] your question with the result.